# Errors when compiling code from Practical Programming 2nd with Custom header

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm starting with the first example from PPP2nd and immediately I have encountered significant issue with the custom header. I have put the header in the compiler include directory for ease of access. Both VS 2010 and 2012 will not compile. Your help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <std_lib_facilities.h>

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello,world\n";
    return 0;
}
```

```
Error   1   error C2868: 'std::vector<_Ty,_Alloc>::size_type' : illegal syntax for using-declaration; expected qualified-name   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\std_lib_facilities.h 71  1   HelloWorld
Error   2   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '='  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\std_lib_facilities.h 71  1   HelloWorld
Error   3   error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\std_lib_facilities.h 71  1   HelloWorld
Error   4   error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'initializer_list'   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\std_lib_facilities.h 80  1   HelloWorld
Error   5   error C2535: 'Vector<T>::Vector(void)' : member function already defined or declared    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\std_lib_facilities.h 80  1   HelloWorld
Error   6   error C2868: 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>::size_type' : illegal syntax for using-declaration; expected qualified-name   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\std_lib_facilities.h 102 1   HelloWorld
Error   7   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '='  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\std_lib_facilities.h 102 1   HelloWorld
Error   8   error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\std_lib_facilities.h 102 1   HelloWorld
Error   9   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\std_lib_facilities.h 213 1   HelloWorld
Error   10  error C2275: 'std::uniform_int_distribution<>' : illegal use of this type as an expression  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\std_lib_facilities.h 213 1   HelloWorld
Error   11  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\std_lib_facilities.h 213 1   HelloWorld
Error   12  error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\std_lib_facilities.h 222 1   HelloWorld
Error   13  error C2059: syntax error : 'using' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\std_lib_facilities.h 222 1   HelloWorld
Error   14  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\std_lib_facilities.h 243 1   HelloWorld
Error   15  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\std_lib_facilities.h 243 1   HelloWorld
Error   16  error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\std_lib_facilities.h 243 1   HelloWorld
Error   17  error C2059: syntax error : '<' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\std_lib_facilities.h 243 1   HelloWorld
Error   18  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\std_lib_facilities.h 251 1   HelloWorld
Error   19  error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?) c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\std_lib_facilities.h 251 1   HelloWorld
    20  IntelliSense: type name is not allowed  c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\std_lib_facilities.h 213 81  HelloWorld
    21  IntelliSense: expected a ';'    c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\std_lib_facilities.h 213 107 HelloWorld
```

Comment: ***Both VS 2010 and 2012 will not compile.*** This is understandable. You are using c++11 code that neither of these handle.

Comment: BTW, In Visual Studio its better to copy the text of error messages from the Output Tab.

Comment: What c++ do they support and what alternative do I have?

Comment: Can you install Visual Studio 2015 Community?

Comment: The author states on his website that VS2010 is supported and actually recommends it...

Comment: @dcrearer  Include before other headers the header "stdafx.h"

Comment: I don't think `std::initializer_list` works with Visual Studio 2010. Here it says you need Visual Studio 2013 or greater: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx

Comment: This is the problem with omnibus header files like  `<std_lib_facilities.h>` and why I don't think they are  ag ood idea, and why I don't think this is a good book to learn C++ from.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow tried that and it does not work.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I agree with you that it is not a book that should be recommended to beginners.

Comment: This really blows my mind that the author documents something that doesn't work.

Comment: Should I try using VS2015 will the experience be improved?

Comment: ***Should I try using VS2015 will the experience be improved?*** Yes for both questions.

Comment: @dcrearer It seems the compiler does not support the using declaration  using size_type = typename std::vector<T>::size_type; in the class template struct Vector

Comment: @dcrearer You can download  free the MS VS 2016 Community.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow downloading MS VS2015 now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to visual studio 2015 allowed me to compile the source file with the customer header file "std_lib_facilities.h" provided by the author.

Thanks all for the guidance and feedback.